# Icons shown in Qt5 not showing in Qt6

Tags: c++, qt5, qt6

I'm writing an application in Qt (Ubuntu 22.10). So far I've been using Qt5, but now I also want to support Qt6. In addition, I created some tool buttons in the application with custom icons. These icons are stored in a resources-file and included in a resources.qrc, which is then called in the CMakeLists.txt.
As long as I am using Qt5, the icons are showing properly. But when using Qt6, the icons are not shown anymore. I wrote a very small example application for a problem showcase.
With Qt5, the output looks like this:

[image: Qt5]

While for Qt6, it looks like this:

[image: Qt6]

The code for the application is shown here:

main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QToolButton>
#include <QWidget>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    // main window
    QMainWindow mainWindow;
    mainWindow.resize(100, 100);

    auto* const toolButton = new QToolButton;
    toolButton->setIcon(QIcon(":icons/gear.svg"));

    auto* const layout = new QHBoxLayout;
    layout->addWidget(toolButton);

    auto* const centralWidget = new QWidget;
    centralWidget->setLayout(layout);

    mainWindow.setCentralWidget(centralWidget);
    mainWindow.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

project(MinimalDemo LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(Qt6 COMPONENTS Widgets)

if(${Qt6_FOUND})
    find_package(QT NAMES Qt6 COMPONENTS Widgets REQUIRED)
    find_package(Qt6 COMPONENTS Widgets REQUIRED)
else()
    find_package(QT NAMES Qt5 COMPONENTS Widgets REQUIRED)
    find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Widgets REQUIRED)
endif()

add_executable(MinimalDemo
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/main.cpp
    resources/resources.qrc
)

target_include_directories (MinimalDemo
    PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
)

target_link_libraries(MinimalDemo
    PRIVATE Qt::Widgets
)
```

And the resources.qrc:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource>
        <file>icons/gear.svg</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

The application's basic file structure is like this:

```
main.cpp
resources
    icons
        gear.svg
```

So obviously, no icon is shown.
As far as I know, the Qt resource handling with qrc files didn't really change in version 6, the handling should be the same. But where is the problem? Did I make a mistake in the CMakeLists.txt, do I have to make additional adjustments for Qt6? Or is the problem somewhere else? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: have you checked the console/debug output for errors?

Comment: Good you're mentioning that. In Qt5, if the icon path is set wrong in the code (for ecample `toolButton->setIcon(QIcon("gea_r.svg"));`, a debug message is thrown that the icon could not be found. For Qt6, this does not appear.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, it seems I found the reason for this behavior. The problem is not in the code itself, but rather in Qt6's package handling.
It seems that the svg submodule has to be installed as an extra package for Qt6, which was not necessary for Qt5. You can install it for Ubuntu like this:
`sudo apt install libqt6svg6`

It should be fine then. No idea what to do for Windows, though.
An alternative if you do not want to use extra packages is to convert the svg files to png. Then it should also work.

EDIT (12.02.2024): So I found a solution if you have this problem on Windows:
What I did was that I put the `Qt6Svg.dll` in the same folder as the exe-file for my application. In addition, I created a subfolder `imageformats` in the same dir as the exe and pasted `qsvg.dll` in it.